# I want to make the data at one place from two different table in one query i have to make the use of pivot

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make the data at one place from two different table in one query i have to make the use of pivot and in the other query i want to sum up the total of the bill of there same customer name which is coming from table 1

Table 1 Query

```
SELECT Cname
      ,Advance
      ,Bill
      ,Refund
FROM   (
           SELECT cname
                 ,r.Amount
                 ,R.PaymentType
           FROM   ReceiptDetails r
       ) AS sourcetable 
       PIVOT(
           SUM(Amount)FOR PaymentType IN ([Advance] ,[Bill] ,[Refund])
       ) AS PivotTable
```

Table 2 Query

```
SELECT Cname
      ,SUM(cb.totalandvat)
FROM   Customer_Bill
```

Cname is common field in both the table

Basially i want to generate the dues list of the customers so from table one(Recipt Details) Name,(Sum of) Advance and other payment they have made and from the second table (Bill Details) The sum of Total amount from the multiple bills

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a *full outer join* beteen the two ueries like this:

```
SELECT
     CName   = coalesce(payment.cname,bill.cname)
    ,bill    = coalesce(bill.Amount)
    ,Advance = coalesce(payment.Advance,0)
    ,Bill    = coalesce(payment.Bill    ,0)
    ,Refund  = coalesce(payment.Refund  ,0)
FROM (
    SELECT Cname
          ,Advance
          ,Bill
          ,Refund
    FROM   (
           SELECT cname
                 ,r.Amount
                 ,R.PaymentType
           FROM   ReceiptDetails r
       ) AS sourcetable 
       PIVOT(
           SUM(Amount)FOR PaymentType IN ([Advance] ,[Bill] ,[Refund])
       ) AS PivotTable
) Payment
full outer join (
    SELECT Cname
      ,SUM(cb.totalandvat) AS Amount
    FROM   Customer_Bill
) bill
ON payment.cname = bill.cname
```

Comment: Hi am using sql server 2008 it is giving following error while running the above queryMsg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near 'Payment'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'bill'.

Comment: Your `FULL JOIN` join-condition is missing Pieter.